# Cannot create system.img when recompiling Android

Tags: android

I wan to recompile android project. I followed steps [here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html)...but every time after ~2 hrs of processing (with no errors I guess), I cannot find the "system.img" file in the output directory. I can find the other 2 files ramdisk.img, userdata.img and extracted system folder, but not system.img.

This causes the emulator to give this error when trying to run it:

> emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it working now. I found that the error occurred while compiling "libwebcore" module so it ends the process.

I found the solution [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-porting/12akwmrgs7/ld-error-when-compile-the-libwebcore-so).

1- I cleaned the build files for libwebcore only not to clean all
builds, otherwise, we will have to redo all build again

```
make clean-libwebcore
```

2- I build only the libwebcore modules to be concerned only about
it until it gets to success.

```
make -j8 libwebcore
```

3- You just have to launch a normal build process with make to go on
building the other remaining modules *

```
make -j8
```